# Is "broadsheet newspaper" redundant?

Tags: usage

Meaning of  [**Broadsheet**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/broadsheet)

When the meaning of **broadsheet** already contains **newspaper** then why in the following sentence

[My focus is restricted to ***serious broadsheet newspapers*** alone.](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/columns/noise-too-is-a-form-of-censorship/article27406775.ece)

the term ***broadsheet newspaper***.  Isn't it redundant?

Answer (score 2):

No, **broadsheet** is a more general term as given by the Oxford Dictionaries [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/broadsheet) with its more specific use defined too.

> **broadsheet**
>   NOUN
>
> **1** A large piece of paper printed with information on one side only.
>
> *I have sent you a broadsheet which surveys our campaigns*
>
> **1.1** A newspaper with a large format, regarded as more serious and less sensationalist than tabloids.
>
> *the tabloidization of the broadsheets*
>
> *They're not going to make a decision and say, ‘Oh look, I'm going to go to a website instead of  going to my broadsheet newspaper.’*

So the proper term is a "broadsheet newspaper" but is usually abbreviated to "broadsheet".

Comment: Broadsheet is a more *specific* term, whereas newspaper is more general.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik edited, thank you, but "particular" and "specific" are quite close synonyms. The more general term is as I wrote: a broad sheet. The newspaper is a specific usage of that.

Comment: No, there are many types of newspapers - magazine format, tabloid, etc. Broadseet is a specific type of newspaper. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspaper_format

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Neither is a subset of the other. Both refer to printed documents, one refers to the content and the other to the size and format of the paper. A newspaper may be printed in broadsheet format, but so may a play, or a piece of music. A broadsheet can be something other than a newspaper, though in modern usage broadsheet has come to mean a specific type of newspaper.

Comment: In English, adjectives come generally first. Broadsheet is the modifier.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  you're assuming "broadsheet" is an adjective.  Most dictionaries list it as a *noun*, making "broadsheet newspaper" a *compound* noun.